# MySQL create view: duplicate rows which has different value in 4 columns and not empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like :

```
   CPID  CID    U1     U2     U3     U4
    1    44    Day    Hour   Null   Year
    2    45    Day    Year   Null   Null
```

i want to make a view to duplicate row if has more than one kind of unit (Ux)

the above will be like this:

```
   CPID  CID    Ux     
    1    44    Day
    1    44    Hour
    1    44    Year
    2    45    Day
    2    45    Year
```

what i did so far is only :

```
SELECT CPID AS CPID,
  CID AS CID,
  Concat_Ws(',', T1, T2, T3, T4) AS Ux
```

above will only show :

```
   CPID  CID    Ux     
    1    44    Day,Hour,Year
    2    45    Day,Year
```

i am still new in MySQL and i think making duplicate/add/edit is not possible in view i would be thankful for your suggestions.

Comment: Try with Union All/Pivot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `UNION ALL`, one SELECT for each U*n* column:

```
select CPID, CID, UX
from
(
select CPID, CID, U1 as UX from tablename
union all
select CPID, CID, U2 as UX from tablename
union all
select CPID, CID, U3 as UX from tablename
union all
select CPID, CID, U4 as UX from tablename
) dt
where ux is not null
```

And, if the result-set order is of importance, add the following row at the end:

```
order by CPID, CID, Ux
```

Seems like MySQL didn't like the above query's derived table when `CREATE VIEW`. Here comes another try:

```
create view viewname (CPID, CID, UX) AS
select CPID, CID, U1 from tablename
where U1 is not null
union all
select CPID, CID, U2 from tablename
where U2 is not null
union all
select CPID, CID, U3 from tablename
where U3 is not null
union all
select CPID, CID, U4 from tablename
where U4 is not null
```

Comment: An `ORDER BY` would make the answer complete.

Comment: @1000111, as requested!

Comment: this is correct but i get this error :  #1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: @Hemin - Give the sub query an alias...   `)   AS pivoted   WHERE ux IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @MatBailie, is that some kind of MySQL restriction?

Comment: i also got this error Every derived table must have its own alias but fixed it by adding an alias before where

Comment: A added a table alias dt, to the derived table. Seems like some products need them, and others don't like them... Optional according to ANSI SQL.

Comment: its working if i use it as an sql query but not if i want to create a view same error :#1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: I'll add another version, without the derived table.

Comment: works great thanks a lot. there was a small warning when creating the view but worked no problem.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `union all`:

```
select cpid, cid, u1 as unit
from t
where u1 is not null and
      (u1 is not null) + (u2 is not null) + (u3 is not null) + (u4 is not null) >= 2
union all
select cpid, cid, u2 as unit
from t
where u2 is not null and
      (u1 is not null) + (u2 is not null) + (u3 is not null) + (u4 is not null) >= 2
select cpid, cid, u3 as unit
from t
where u3 is not null and
      (u1 is not null) + (u2 is not null) + (u3 is not null) + (u4 is not null) >= 2
select cpid, cid, u4 as unit
from t
where u4 is not null and
      (u1 is not null) + (u2 is not null) + (u3 is not null) + (u4 is not null) >= 2;
```

The trick is the condition "if has more than one kind of unit". This requires counting the number of non-NULL values in each row.  This method uses a feature of MySQL where a boolean expression is treated as "1" for true and "0" for false.  So, adding the boolean expressions together has the effect of counting them.

Comment: I don't understand this where clause, why do you need to check columns for nulls that are not being selected? I have a feeling one of us misinterpreted the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT CPID,CID,U1 FROM YourTable
WHERE U1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT CPID,CID,U2 FROM YourTable
WHERE U2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT CPID,CID,U3 FROM YourTable
WHERE U3 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT CPID,CID,U4 FROM YourTable
WHERE U4 IS NOT NULL
```